# How to pass parameters to JSP component?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am working with Spring and JSP. How can I pass parameters to

```
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
```

It is like passing prop into components in ReactJS, but I can't find it in any document. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Which parameters , the .xml tiles definition jsp  https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html   or request.getParameter() that you get from query string and check if not == null ?

Answer (score 0):

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/tld-summary.html

Refer to this link for documentation.
In Tiles, every attribute can be determined to have a "type", either set explicitly when it was defined or "computed". If the type is not explicit, then if the attribute value is a valid definition, it will be inserted as such. Otherwise, if it begins with a "/" character, it will be treated as a "template". Finally, if it has not otherwise been assigned a type, it will be treated as a String and included without any special handling.

Put Atttribute -> you declare what content will be associated with specified attribute name:

```
<definition name="admin-template-metronic" extends="metronic-template" template="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/tiles/admin.jsp">
<put-attribute name="html-title" value="Administrative Console"/>
<put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/common/banner.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/common/footer.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="menu-content" value="/WEB-INF/templates/metronic/pages/admin/main-menu.jsp"/>
```

Insert Attribute: it will use the attribute defined up using put-attribute. On your page, banner-content will be replaced with the content of file "banner.jsp"

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="banner-content"/>
```

Now check as per your requirement which one suits you best.